# VirtualBox Hangs when installing freebsd 9.0

Tags: linux, virtualbox, freebsd

When installing Freebsd 9.0 as virtualbox guest, it hangs. Freezes the guest OS, other VirtualBox windows works fine.
Logs attached, hardware is pentium D, 4 GB ram, Asus p5ld2 deluxe mainboard, OS - Ubuntu linux.
When I select minimum configuration as possible, freebsd was installed in this minimal configuration. Then I tried to install KDE from ftp, and after downloading some packages, it hangs again on downloading ghostscript.

How fix this?

[I asked this on virtualbox forum too](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=48561)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a network / firewall problem ?

Comment: What is the version of virtual box that you are using? Sometimes disabling powerd helps. And check what version of the OS you are running. 64bit VM on 32bit OS that kind of combinations. Virtualbox will not complain about a mismatch, but sometimes these strange symptoms disappear when "correctly" matching this.

Comment: It says in the logs that the filesystem on your virtual hard disk is unknown. How did you create the virtual disk image to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this going to help you but try it. Select your virtual machine from virtualbox, click on **Settings**, chose **System**, a new window will popup, in the **extended features** section check **Enable I/O APIC**, **Hardware clock in UTC time**, and **Enable absolute pointing device**.